# Form doesn't load in while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a class defined to get live capture from a camera, and a form button "END CAPTURE" that should halt the capture; and an typical Application.Exit() button.

However, for some reason the while loop as shown below doesn't load the form even when the condition is met. To debug this, I commented out the while loop to see if it snaps at least 1 image; and it does  (as shown in fig). What makes the while loop not to load the form and show the output continuously ?

```
while (!terminated)
            {
                // CAMERA ACQUISITION CODE
            }
```

Figure of single while loop run:
[image: 1]

Full program for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using mv.impact.acquire;
using mv.impact.acquire.examples.helper;


namespace mv_BlueFoxControl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool button1WasClicked = false;
        public Bitmap SnappedBitmap = null;
        public static Image PersistentImage = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mv.impact.acquire.LibraryPath.init(); // this will add the folders containing unmanaged libraries to the PATH variable.
            Device pDev = DeviceManager.getDevice(0);// Get a pointer to the first device found 

            if (pDev == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to continue! No device found! Press any key to end the program.");
                //Console.Read();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Initialising the device. This might take some time...");
            try
            {
                pDev.open();//start the sensor
                Console.WriteLine("Device opened successfully...");
            }
            catch (ImpactAcquireException e)
            {
                // throw error code if the same device is already opened in another process...
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while opening the device " + pDev.serial +
                    "(error code: " + e.Message + "). Press any key to end the application...");
                //Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            bool terminated = false;// Bool terminated was here.
            Console.WriteLine("Press CAPTURE to end the application");
            // create thread for live capture
            Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()//Start live acquisition
            {
                DeviceAccess.manuallyStartAcquisitionIfNeeded(pDev, fi);
                Request pRequest = null;
                // we always have to keep at least 2 images as the display module might want to repaint the image, thus we
                // can free it unless we have a assigned the display to a new buffer.
                Request pPreviousRequest = null;                
                int timeout_ms = 500;
                int cnt = 0;
                int requestNr = Device.INVALID_ID;
                Console.WriteLine(terminated); 
                while (!terminated)
                {
                    // CAMERA ACQUISITON CODE
                }
                DeviceAccess.manuallyStopAcquisitionIfNeeded(pDev, fi);                
                // free the last potential locked request
                if (pRequest != null)
                {
                    pRequest.unlock();
                }
                // clear the request queue
                fi.imageRequestReset(0, 0);
                // extract and unlock all requests that are now returned as 'aborted'
                requestNr = Device.INVALID_ID;
                while ((requestNr = fi.imageRequestWaitFor(0)) >= 0)
                {
                    pRequest = fi.getRequest(requestNr);
                    Console.WriteLine("Request {0} did return with status {1}", requestNr, pRequest.requestResult.readS());
                    pRequest.unlock();
                }
            });//End of thread
            Console.WriteLine(" End Thread");
            thread.Start();
            if (button1WasClicked)
            {
                terminated = true;
            }            
            Console.WriteLine("Program termination");
            Console.WriteLine(terminated);
            thread.Join();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1WasClicked = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What currently is missing in the code is, how do you bring the image you got in the worker thread into the gui? E.g. if you simply apply the image to a picture box while you are in the worker thread, that won't work. You have to dispatch this set call back to the gui thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of thread.Join(); The application will wait that the thread ends (which will not end until you press the button) and so the constructor is never finished.

You have to initialize a Thread field and only close it when you press the button.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //...
    private Thread _cameraThread;

    public Form1()
    {
        //... the previous code 

        _cameraThread = new Thread(delegate()//Start live acquisition
        {
            // thread logic 
        });

        _cameraThread.Start();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1WasClicked = true;
        //set the flag and wait for the thread to finish
        _cameraThread.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Program termination");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Works now. But when I run the program and click Capture I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mv-BlueFoxControl.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Also the application doesnt exit when I click Exit. Why would that happen.

Comment: Can't you check by Visual Studio which object is null? Or log the exception with the stack trace.

Comment: It just says; Error 1: 'mv_BlueFoxControl.Form1._cameraThread' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: I forgot to delete the word 'thread' in this line '_cameraThread thread = new Thread(delegate()...' My bad
Updated the answer.